# How to select a value of type date as "DD-MM-YYYY" in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I have a column `creationDate` which of type `date` in a SQL Server database table. I want to select it as `DD-MM-YYYY` format.

However, there is an error when I try to use

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), creationDate, 105) 
FROM tableName
```

in my C# application.

The error message is:

> A field or property with the name 'creationDate ' was not found on the
>   selected data source.

Comment: This has nothing to do with dates conversions. I bet `SELECT creationDate FROM tableName` doesn't work. Use `SELECT * FROM creationDate ` and check the exact name of the column.

Comment: Sidenote: use `char(10)` instead of `varchar(10)`. the convert will always return 10 chars with this style.

Comment: @user3185569 it is successfully to 'SELECT creationDate FROM tableName', but the result will be 7/29/2016 12:00:00 AM...

Comment: Almost always better to leave such formatting details to the application or report processor that's *consuming* this result set, rather than doing it down in the SQL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK...but why? My SQL SERVER has high spec hardware, but client devices have not.. It should be a better performance with doing calculation in server intend of client devices

Comment: It's not about performance. It's about keeping things in their natural data types rather than as strings - you may not have any requirements at the moment for any post-processing at the client, but as soon as requirements like sorting or applying the client's locale settings are raised, it's far easier to work from the original data rather than strings. Plus, most languages have richer text-processing facilities that T-SQL does.

Comment: If it's a 3 layer architecture, that should happen on the application server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't provide any default alias name to output columns. Your current query `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), creationDate, 105) FROM tableName` doesn't output `creationDate` column name as shown in the snapshot below. It says - `(No column name)`:

[image]

You must give a column alias name in your SQL query for C# to capture on application side as shown in the snapshot below:

`SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), creationDate, 105) AS [creationdate] FROM tableName`

[image]

This should solve your problem but it is always advised that you should do such conversions on application layer as `many a times such conversions will require taking locale and time-zone of your client computer (where the application is running) into consideration`. This happens as developers generally store date time data in database in GMT in 24 hour date-time format.

Answer (score 3):

Set an alias name for that column in your query to resolve your issue

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), creationDate, 105) [creationDate] FROM tableName
```

Comment: formatting should be at the front end. Not at data level.